# Analogy between logical formula and random variable

Tags: logic, soft-question, random-variables

A logical formula $\phi$ induces a function from the space of valuations to the set $\{0,1\}$. Similarly, a binary random variable is a function from a sample space $\Omega$ to $\{0,1\}$. If we think of the space of valuations as a sample space, and think of valuations as outcomes, then each logical formula corresponds to a random variable. Then, a collection of logical formulae induces a $\sigma$-algebra on the set of valuations, and knowing the truth values of some collection of logical formulae tells us something about which elements of that $\sigma$-algebra our valuation belongs to.

Has anyone investigated this connection between logic and probability? Is the analogy here useful or it just surface-level?

Comment: The algebraic semantic of probability theory is a σ-algebra of set while the algebraic semantic of Łukasiewicz logic is an [MV-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MV-algebra). The former mainly captures our partial knowledge of factual truth which itself has no vagueness, while the latter treats any fact as partial truth. This can be reflected by σ-algebra's use in defining probability *measure*, while MV-algebra is used to form *lattice* not any measure...

Comment: Another difference is for random variables we have conditional expectation and probability induced by its sub σ-algebra, while we don't have the concept of conditional (partial) truth induced from a sub lattice.